# Растягивание кубика между двумя точками

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть 2 точки, между которыми создается при запуске кубик. При отдалении одного, от другого он должен менять скейл и так же перемещаться между этими двумя точками. Эта задача была легко повержена. Проблема в повороте самого кубика, при изменении положения точки. На одну ось, по отдельности работает отлично. но если задействовать две, а то и три оси - начинается какое то не ведомое мне волшебство... кубик или фристайл крутит, или крутиться не в ту сторону.. В общем не хочет поворачиваться кубик так как мне нужно. Скрипты прикладываю:
Код которые висит на кубике самом...

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RotationScriptInst : MonoBehaviour {
    Quaternion originQuternion;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        originQuternion = transform.rotation;

    }
    public void RotationInst(float RotX,float RotY,float RotZ)
    {
        // преобразоывание градусов в эйлеры
        Quaternion RotYQuat = Quaternion.AngleAxis(RotY, Vector3.up);
        Quaternion RotXQuat = Quaternion.AngleAxis(RotX, Vector3.right);
        Quaternion RotZQuat = Quaternion.AngleAxis(RotZ, Vector3.forward);
        // преобразоывание градусов в эйлеры \\
        //this.transform.rotation = originQuternion * RotXQuat * RotYQuat; // использую эйлеры
        this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(-RotX, RotY, -RotZ); // использую градусы
    }
}
```

Код который висит на отдельном объекте:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class InstScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject  Empty1, Empty2, InstObject; // объекты: 1 и 2 точки и префаб кубика
    public Vector3 InstObjectPosition; // центральная точка, где должен быть кубик
    private float InstObjectScale, mousex, mousey, mousexnormal, mouseynormal; // скейл, мышьХ,мышьУ и начальные точки мыши(не актуально
    public GameObject inst; // сам кубик при инстанте сюда присваивается
    public float Rotx, Roty, Rotz, CosX, CosY, CosZ; // углы и коссинусы поворотов
    private float RotxP, RotyP, RotzP; // предыдущие значения углов
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        //находится центральная точка
        InstObjectPosition = new Vector3((Empty1.transform.position.x + Empty2.transform.position.x) / 2, (Empty1.transform.position.y + Empty2.transform.position.y) / 2, (Empty1.transform.position.z + Empty2.transform.position.z) / 2);
        // находится скейл
        InstObjectScale = Mathf.Sqrt(
            (Empty1.transform.position.x - Empty2.transform.position.x) * (Empty1.transform.position.x - Empty2.transform.position.x) +
            (Empty1.transform.position.y - Empty2.transform.position.y) * (Empty1.transform.position.y - Empty2.transform.position.y) +
            (Empty1.transform.position.z - Empty2.transform.position.z) * (Empty1.transform.position.z - Empty2.transform.position.z)
        );
        //создаем объект
        inst = Instantiate(InstObject, InstObjectPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        inst.transform.localScale = new Vector3(InstObjectScale, InstObjectScale, InstObjectScale);
        //для упарвления мышью
        mousexnormal = Input.mousePosition.x;
        mouseynormal = Input.mousePosition.y;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () {
        // тот же самый код что в начале
        InstObjectPosition = new Vector3((Empty1.transform.position.x + Empty2.transform.position.x) / 2, (Empty1.transform.position.y + Empty2.transform.position.y) / 2, (Empty1.transform.position.z + Empty2.transform.position.z) / 2);
        InstObjectScale = Mathf.Sqrt(
            (Empty1.transform.position.x - Empty2.transform.position.x) * (Empty1.transform.position.x - Empty2.transform.position.x) +
            (Empty1.transform.position.y - Empty2.transform.position.y) * (Empty1.transform.position.y - Empty2.transform.position.y) +
            (Empty1.transform.position.z - Empty2.transform.position.z) * (Empty1.transform.position.z - Empty2.transform.position.z)
        );
        // енд старт код
        // находим коссинус Х
        CosX =
        (Empty2.transform.position.z - Empty1.transform.position.z) /
        Mathf.Sqrt(
            (Empty2.transform.position.y - Empty1.transform.position.y) * (Empty2.transform.position.y - Empty1.transform.position.y) +
            (Empty2.transform.position.z - Empty1.transform.position.z) * (Empty2.transform.position.z - Empty1.transform.position.z)
        );
        // находим угол Х
        Rotx =  Mathf.Acos(CosX) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        // находим коссинус У
        CosY =
        (Empty2.transform.position.x - Empty1.transform.position.x) /
        Mathf.Sqrt(
            (Empty2.transform.position.x - Empty1.transform.position.x) * (Empty2.transform.position.x - Empty1.transform.position.x) +
            (Empty2.transform.position.z - Empty1.transform.position.z) * (Empty2.transform.position.z - Empty1.transform.position.z)
        );
        //Так же находим угол (с минусом стабильнее)
        Roty = -1 * Mathf.Acos(CosY) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        //находим коссинус Z
        CosZ =
        (Empty2.transform.position.y - Empty1.transform.position.y) /
        Mathf.Sqrt(
            (Empty2.transform.position.x - Empty1.transform.position.x) * (Empty2.transform.position.x - Empty1.transform.position.x) +
            (Empty2.transform.position.y - Empty1.transform.position.y) * (Empty2.transform.position.y - Empty1.transform.position.y)
        );
        //в свою очередь и угол тоже
        Rotz = -1 * Mathf.Acos(CosZ) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        inst.transform.position = InstObjectPosition; // присваиваем позицию
        inst.transform.localScale = new Vector3(InstObjectScale, InstObjectScale, InstObjectScale); // присваиваем скейл
        inst.GetComponent<RotationScriptInst>().RotationInst(Rotx, Roty, Rotz); // изменяем угол
        // код для упраавления мышью
        mousex = Input.mousePosition.x;
        //Empty1.transform.position = new Vector3((mousex - mousexnormal) / 15 , 0, 0);
        mousey = Input.mousePosition.y;
        //Empty2.transform.position = new Vector3((mousey - mouseynormal) / 15 , 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Вот гиф:
[image: gif]
[image: описание задачи]

Comment: Можете это показать гифом? Просто было бы удобно понять траекторию.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону [`Quaternion.LookRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html).

Comment: @Alt_F4 сделал.

Comment: @tebenkov2222 задачка интересная. Вы не против если я попробую сам написать и не посмотрю ваш код?

Comment: @Alt_F4 Нет конечно же) У меня типичная тригонометрия

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вместо `Quaternion.LookRotation` я использовал `LookAt`.

---

Работоспособность

[image]

---

Код

```
public class ControlScript: MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector3 firstPoint, secondPoint;
    public GameObject Cube, LeftSphere, RightSphere;
    public bool position, scale, rotation;

    private void Update()
    {
        firstPoint = LeftSphere.transform.position;
        secondPoint = RightSphere.transform.position;

        if (position)
        {
            PositionControl();
        }

        if (scale)
        {
            ScaleControl();
        }

        if (rotation)
        {
            RotationControl();
        }
    }

    void PositionControl()
    {
        Vector3 center = new Vector3((firstPoint.x + secondPoint.x) / 2, (firstPoint.y + secondPoint.y) / 2, (firstPoint.z + secondPoint.z) / 2);

        Cube.transform.position = center;
    }

    void ScaleControl()
    {
        float spaceBetween = Mathf.Sqrt
        (
            Mathf.Pow(firstPoint.x - secondPoint.x, 2) +
            Mathf.Pow(firstPoint.y - secondPoint.y, 2) +
            Mathf.Pow(firstPoint.z - secondPoint.z, 2)
        );

        Cube.transform.localScale = new Vector3(spaceBetween, spaceBetween, spaceBetween);
    }

    void RotationControl()
    {
        Cube.transform.LookAt(RightSphere.transform);
    }
}
```

Comment: А куда скрипт кидать?

Comment: @tebenkov2222 Я писал скрипт таким что не важно куда он будет только надо там в скрипте кубик и обе сферы поставить